# How to escape '!' when call angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

AngularJS filter protected some special chars. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with `!`, but now I want to filter out the items which contains the '!' special char. How can I escapes this special char '!' please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't escape it, because `filter` filter [doesn't presume it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L208).

But you can use [predicate function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to override default behaviour for `!` predicate and decorate `filter` without breaking anything else.

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
  function bang(value) {
    return value.indexOf('!') >= 0;
  };

  function bangless(value) {
    return value.indexOf('!') < 0;
  };

  $provide.decorator('filterFilter', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    return function (array, expression, comparator) {
      if (expression === '!') {
        expression = bang;
      } else if (expression === '!!') {
        expression = bangless;
      }

      return $delegate(array, expression, comparator);
    }
  }]);
}]);
```