# Angular filter issue, fails for special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using Angular Filter for a while now,
If I use "!@#" string in search box. The filter service doesnot work.

See this example on Angular Site

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955000/how-to-escape-when-call-angularjs-filter helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ! preceding a string (@#) will find all that does not match (negates) @#. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter Seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Thanx Ultradiv, this can be a reason, but "!"  should be treated as string not negator.